# Google Tag Manager Invalid HTML, CSS, or JavaScript found in template helpl pls

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use GTM's "Custom HTML Tag" option with the following code but it is giving me the following error: Invalid HTML, CSS, or JavaScript found in template.

I've seen other threads where it looks like GTM doesn't work well with certain tag attributes. I'm wondering which one in my code is breaking it. Otherwise the code seems to be standard javascript:

```
<div id="id-custom_banner" style="width: 100%; position: fixed; left: 0; bottom: 0; z-index: 999999; opacity: 1; transition: bottom 1.5s ease-out 0s, opacity .2s ease-out 1s, transform .2s ease-out 0s; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); backdrop-filter: blur(5px); display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;"><div style="position: absolute; right: 0; top: -21px; cursor: pointer" onclick="removeCustomBanner(this.parentNode);"><svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 16.6 17" style="width: 20px; height: 20px; filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 2px #333); -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 2px #333)"><polygon fill="#FFF" points="15.5,1.7 13.7,0 7.7,6.1 1.8,0 0,1.7 6,7.9 0,14.1 1.8,15.9 7.7,9.7 13.7,15.9 15.5,14.1 9.5,7.9 "></polygon></svg></div><div class="timer" style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 10; padding: 5px; color: #fff"></div>here add</div>';
    <div>
<span   
style.width = "100%";
style.position = "fixed";
style.left = "0";
style.bottom = "0";
style.zIndex = "999999";
style.opacity = "1";
style.transition = "bottom 1.5s ease-out 0s, opacity .2s ease-out 1s, transform .2s ease-out 0s";
style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)";
style.backdropFilter = "blur(5px)";></span>
 </div>
    <script>
function removeCustomBanner(element) {
  element.remove();
}
    </script>
```

Comment: i think the inline css is messed up??

Answer (score 0):

Using SVG markup directly in a custom html tag seems not to be possible/allowed: https://support.google.com/tagmanager/thread/75802051/unable-to-include-a-svg-in-a-custom-html-tag?hl=en

But there are at least two possible workarounds:

- `<img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,...">`
- `background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg>...</svg>');`

Just look for a SVG to data uri converter, like https://davidgierth.de/tools/svg-to-data-uri/